# Numpy: Optimal way to count indexs occurrence in an array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, parallel-processing, torch

I have an array `indexs`. It's very long (>10k), and each int value is rather small (<100). e.g.

```py
indexs = np.array([1, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]) # int index array
indexs_max = 4 # already known
```

Now I want to count occurrence of each index value (e.g. 0 for 3 times, 1 for 2 times...), and get `counts` as `np.array([3, 2, 1, 1, 1])`. I have tested 4 methods as follows:

`UPDATE`: `_test4` is @[Ch3steR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65336241/13571357)'s sol:

---

```py
indexs = np.random.randint(0, 10, (20000,))
indexs_max = 9

def _test1():
    counts = np.zeros((indexs_max + 1, ), dtype=np.int32)
    for ind in indexs:
        counts[ind] += 1
    return counts

def _test2():
    counts = np.zeros((indexs_max + 1,), dtype=np.int32)
    uniq_vals, uniq_cnts = np.unique(indexs, return_counts=True)
    counts[uniq_vals] = uniq_cnts
    # this is because some value in range may be missing
    return counts

def _test3():
    therange = np.arange(0, indexs_max + 1)
    counts = np.sum(indexs[None] == therange[:, None], axis=1)
    return counts

def _test4():
    return np.bincount(indexs, minlength=indexs_max+1)
```

Run for 500 times, their time usage are respectively `32.499472856521606s`, `0.31386804580688477s`, `0.14069509506225586s`, `0.017721891403198242s`. <del>Although `_test3` is the fastest, it uses additional big memory.</del>

So I'm asking for any better methods. Thank u :) (@[Ch3steR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65336241/13571357))

---

`UPDATE`: `np.bincount` seems optimal so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to count the occurrences in an array.

```
indexs = np.array([1, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0])
np.bincount(indexs)
# array([3, 2,  1,  1,  1])
#        0's 1's 2's 3's 4's count
```

There's a caveat to it `np.bincount(x).size == np.amax(x)+1`

> Example:
>
> ```
> indexs = np.array([5, 10])
> np.bincount(indexs)
> # array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
> #                       5's            10's count
> ```
>
> Here's it would count occurrences of 0 to the max in the array, a workaround can be
>
> ```
> c = np.bincount(indexs) # indexs is [5, 10]
> c = c[c>0]
> # array([1,  1])
> #        5's 10's count
> ```
>
> If you have no missing values from i.e from `0` to `your_max` you can use `np.bincount`.

Another caveat:

From docs:

> Count the number of occurrences of each value in an array of non-negative ints.

Comment: Great! `test4` is `bincount`:
`
time usage in (s):
test1: 32.499472856521606
test2: 0.31386804580688477
test3: 0.14069509506225586
test4: 0.017721891403198242
`